# Can't have consecutive rows with the same value with bit datatype in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, boolean, columnsorting

I'm doing a calendar program and for my database I'm using MySQL.

I have a table called 'evento' (event) in which one of the columns is a Boolean called 'Tarea' (Pending). This column is used to determine if the event is marked a pending or not.

[image: Image of the table]

I researched and the data type for Booleans in MySQL appears to be bit. The problem that Im having is that every time I input elements into the table, the bit variable has to be 0 and 1 but in a consecutive order meaning I cant have two or more rows that consecutively have the value 0 or 1.

[image: Image of the table and the bit column]

When I try to modify the value in the bit column and it doesn't match the consecutive 1 and 0 like for example:

```
UPDATE `calendario`.`evento` SET `Tarea` = '0' WHERE (`idevento` = '6'); 
//when the row with id = 5 or 7 has a value of 0 as well`
```

MySQL props me with the error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
UPDATE `calendario`.`evento` SET `Tarea` = '0' WHERE (`idevento` = '6');

ERROR 1406: 1406: Data too long for column 'Tarea' at row 1
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `calendario`.`evento` SET `Tarea` = '0' WHERE (`idevento` = '6')
```

Is there any way to solve this issue or am I maybe using the wrong datatype? Help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Typically tinyint(1) is used for booleans.  In fact you can specify `bool` as the type, but that's just an alias for tinyint(1).  https://dbfiddle.uk/4D5_o926

Comment: thank you, I used tinyint(1) and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'0'` isn't zero, it's the **character** that represents zero. Lose the quotes and you should be OK:

```sql
UPDATE `calendario`.`evento` SET `Tarea` = 0 WHERE (`idevento` = '6'); 
-- Here -----------------------------------^
```